# Consultas MYSQL dos tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql, html5, imagen, tablas

Un poco de contexto: Soy un universitario que está haciendo servicio social para una secundaria, como proyecto me pidieron una base de datos con ABC para tema de reportes, es decir el área encargada de presentar reportes a los alumnos.
Mediante tutoriales ya logré crear las altas en las que se sube una imagen,un dato de campo texto y una matricula (Matricula creada para unir una tabla de datos de los ALUMNOS <nombre,apellidos,etc> y otra tabla para únicamente datos de REPORTES <imagen escaneada del reporte,texto>).

El caso es el siguiente:
Para hacer la consulta la idea es que por ejemplo Carlitos con matricula 20104095, recibió n numero de reportes, al hacer la consulta en la página mediante un formulario escribir el nombre y la página en una tabla imprima datos generales como el nombre, apellidos, matricula y del reporte en cuestion: imagen y nombre del maestro a cargo .

Mi código para hacer la consulta es el siguiente:

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 r INNER JOIN $tabla_db1 a ON r.Alumno_matricula = a.matricula")
or die ("Hubo problemas con la consulta");

Visualmente se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que al escribir en ese formulario se consulten los datos especificos?
Y que si solo quiero ver los reportes de Carlitos se muestren todos los reportes pero solo de Carlitos

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 r INNER JOIN $tabla_db1 a ON r.Alumno_matricula = a.matricula WHERE r.Alumno_matricula = 20104095;`

Comment: Hola!
Entiendo tu solución, pero tal vez yo plantee mal la pregunta, al ser un sistema de reportes las consultas son cambiantes entre diferentes matriculas, es decir si buscamos a Carlitos tu función me sirve, pero si unos minutos después quieren buscara a "Andrea" con matricula diferente, ¿Cuál sería la solución?

Comment: En lugar que busques por el  nombre, has que tu consulta obtenga la matricula, una vez que ya tienes la matricula sera el dato que te permita la búsqueda solo de esa matricula.

Comment: Sí te entendí bien Cesar, entonces que el formulario busque solo por la matricula y en el php hacer un WHERE de únicamente el dato de matricula?

Comment: Se logró Familia JAJAJA.
Ahora estuve viendo la función de GROUP_CONCAT Para mostrar los diversos reportes que tiene una persona, pero me marca error, aún no lo entiendo
ósea que 
Pablo actualmente tiene 2 reportes y Marco uno
Si quiero ver los reportes de Pablo ingreso la matricula todo va bien pero solo me muestra un solo reporte, no ambos :(

Comment: entonces esta mal tu query, o como lo mostras en pantalla.. proba primero tu query.. y actualiza la pregunta... creo que deberias tambien leer un poco de sql, porque lo que estas preguntando es el funcionamiento basico, y si seguis asi, vas a preguntar por cada consulta...